# passing varables' value from one form to another in php

Tags: php, sql

I have three forms - `payment.php`  , `payment1.php` and  `paydb.php` . `payment.php` contains the front end form.`payment1.php` contains the back end of the form of `payment.php`. whereas we are shifting to `paydb.php` from `payment1.php`. Now I'm filling the form by entering member number in `payment.php` which is retrieved in a variable `$member_no` in `payment1.php` .Now I want to get the value of `member_no` in `paydb.php` . How to do that ?

Comment: Do you already have the value of `$member_no` when you get to `payment.php`? OR is that value on that page? Sensitive information such as member numbers should be handled very carefully and never shown to the public.

Comment: @Kuya : I get the value by this  `$member_no = $_REQUEST['member_no']`  in `payment1.php` . Now I want to carry forward this value of   `$member_no`  to `paydb.php` .

Comment: Is your form method `POST` or `GET`? It's very important for your member's security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After receiving $member_no in payment1.php redirect to paybd.php with a get array
using

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/paydb.php?member_no=$member_no');
```

then receive $_GET['member_no'] number and assign to a variable
example:

```
$member_no = $_GET['member_no']
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) What if I have to go thru a form submit button ? I have a submit button in payment1.php , after clicking on that submit button we are redirected to paydb.php . Now could you please help me out with the code ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In this case you don't need to use header function. You can use <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $member_no; ?>' name='member_no'> in payment1.php form. and form action='paybd.php'

Comment: It seems to be a good reply but somehow I'm unable to get results . Its not working @ my end. Do I need to add something else too  ?

Comment: algorithm is sample. you submit a form data to payment1.php and then you receive $member_no = $_REQUEST['member_no'] and then you pass this $member_no to paydb.php through a form. so that your form have a input field to pass this value to paybd.php that's way you need this <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $member_no; ?>' name='member_no'>. After submit payment1.php page this you can receive $member_no = $_REQUEST['member_no'] from paybd.php page

Comment: Ohhh I thought it will work without `$member_no = $_REQUEST[blah ...` ... Thanku sooo much ... It worked ... :) :)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is make sure you are not passing sensitive information where the public can see it. Such as in a URL.

As soon as you get the member's number... store it in a session variable.
You can probably do this when they log in.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['member_no'] = $member_no;
```

OR on the first payment page (assuming 'member_no' is the name of the form element being passed) like this...

```
$_SESSION['member_no'] = $_POST['member_no'];
```

Now that session will persist as long as the visitor has their browser open and you don't have to worry about passing it from page to page.

You can use that session on any subsequent page simply by calling it.

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['member_no'] ?>
```

Without showing this information to the public.

ALWAYS make sure you place this at the top of any page where you want to use session variables.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
```

Comment: emmm what if I feed different value of `$member_no` in different pages of my software ?

Comment: If I am a member of your site... I should only have one member number.

Comment: Its a s/w wherein the administrator  can fill details of  all the associated members . so somewhere he might be using a different member to add/edit whereas somewhere some other members' transaction might take place .. I know I'm bad in explaining .. :/

Comment: At the moment... are we talking about "admin" pages or the "public" pages? I'm sure you're aware things are handled differently in each area. According to your question... we are talking about "public" pages, so that's how I'm answering. Always keep in mind that the security of your members information is in your hands and is an extremely important matter.

Comment: Admin Pages ... Thanku soo much for your kind replies .. Since its my first project and deadlines are near that's why I'm neglecting the security issues as they are not of so much concern . But , next time I would like to refer you for such expert's tips .. :)